# Bounds on binary event estimation

Tags: beta-distribution, bernoulli-process

I would like to paint an objective picture of some binary outcome.

Now I have data like this: 1085x yes, 1704x no. The percentage of the positive outcome is 40.72%, but I want to give an estimation of the uncertainty. (I have multiple rows like this that are independent of each other) I have Googled for bounds on Beta distributions or Bernoulli trials but can't make sense of it.

This unanswered question is related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92948/how-to-measure-whether-the-yes-no-bernoulli-trials-answers-have-converged-abou